# VS2010E Qt 5.1 compilation error LNK2001 LNK2019

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, lnk2019, lnk2001

i'm trying to build a simple Qt window from a photoshop plugin

i put libraries where it belongs
in the Include directory :

```
E:\Program_Files\Qt32\5.1.0\msvc2010\include;
E:\Program_Files\Qt32\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets\;
```

in the library directory :

```
 E:\Program_Files\Qt32\5.1.0\msvc2010\lib;
 E:\Program_Files\Qt32\5.1.0\msvc2010\lib\cmake\Qt5Core;
```

in link>general>directory of additional libraries

```
E:\Program_Files\Qt32\5.1.0\msvc2010\lib\cmake;
E:\Program_Fi
```

les\Qt32\5.1.0\msvc2010\lib\cmake\Qt5Core;

i alos added in link editor>entry>additional dependency

```
Qt5Cored.lib;
Qt5Core.lib;
Qt5Gui.lib;
```

here is what i have : (i use VS2010 Express so i can't use VSadd-in)

i've tried *a lot* of things without luck

thanks

```
1>     Création de la bibliothèque .\..\..\..\Output\Objs\tempproj\Release/tempproj.lib et de l'objet .\..\..\..\Output\Objs\tempproj\Release/tempproj.exp
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QAbstractButton::setText(class QString const &)" (__imp_?setText@QAbstractButton@@QAEXABVQString@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Ui_GradientSelector::retranslateUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?retranslateUi@Ui_GradientSelector@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QWidget::setWindowTitle(class QString const &)" (__imp_?setWindowTitle@QWidget@@QAEXABVQString@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Ui_GradientSelector::retranslateUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?retranslateUi@Ui_GradientSelector@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QMainWindow::~QMainWindow(void)" (__imp_??1QMainWindow@@UAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual __thiscall GradientSelector::~GradientSelector(void)" (??1GradientSelector@@UAE@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall GradientSelector::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@GradientSelector@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void * __thiscall GradientSelector::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@GradientSelector@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall GradientSelector::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@GradientSelector@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QMainWindow::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QMainWindow@@MAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::setVisible(bool)" (?setVisible@QWidget@@UAEX_N@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QWidget::sizeHint(void)const " (?sizeHint@QWidget@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QWidget::minimumSizeHint(void)const " (?minimumSizeHint@QWidget@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QWidget::heightForWidth(int)const " (?heightForWidth@QWidget@@UBEHH@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual bool __thiscall QWidget::hasHeightForWidth(void)const " (?hasHeightForWidth@QWidget@@UBE_NXZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::mousePressEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mousePressEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseReleaseEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseDoubleClickEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseMoveEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::wheelEvent(class QWheelEvent *)" (?wheelEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQWheelEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::keyPressEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyPressEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::keyReleaseEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyReleaseEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::focusInEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusInEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::focusOutEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusOutEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::enterEvent(class QEvent *)" (?enterEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::leaveEvent(class QEvent *)" (?leaveEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::moveEvent(class QMoveEvent *)" (?moveEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQMoveEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQResizeEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::closeEvent(class QCloseEvent *)" (?closeEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQCloseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMainWindow::contextMenuEvent(class QContextMenuEvent *)" (?contextMenuEvent@QMainWindow@@MAEXPAVQContextMenuEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::tabletEvent(class QTabletEvent *)" (?tabletEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQTabletEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::actionEvent(class QActionEvent *)" (?actionEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQActionEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::dragEnterEvent(class QDragEnterEvent *)" (?dragEnterEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQDragEnterEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::dragMoveEvent(class QDragMoveEvent *)" (?dragMoveEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQDragMoveEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::dragLeaveEvent(class QDragLeaveEvent *)" (?dragLeaveEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQDragLeaveEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::dropEvent(class QDropEvent *)" (?dropEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQDropEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::showEvent(class QShowEvent *)" (?showEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQShowEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::hideEvent(class QHideEvent *)" (?hideEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQHideEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QWidget::nativeEvent(class QByteArray const &,void *,long *)" (?nativeEvent@QWidget@@MAE_NABVQByteArray@@PAXPAJ@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::changeEvent(class QEvent *)" (?changeEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::inputMethodEvent(class QInputMethodEvent *)" (?inputMethodEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQInputMethodEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QWidget::inputMethodQuery(enum Qt::InputMethodQuery)const " (?inputMethodQuery@QWidget@@UBE?AVQVariant@@W4InputMethodQuery@Qt@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QWidget::focusNextPrevChild(bool)" (?focusNextPrevChild@QWidget@@MAE_N_N@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QMenu * __thiscall QMainWindow::createPopupMenu(void)" (?createPopupMenu@QMainWindow@@UAEPAVQMenu@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QWidget::devType(void)const " (?devType@QWidget@@UBEHXZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QPaintEngine * __thiscall QWidget::paintEngine(void)const " (?paintEngine@QWidget@@UBEPAVQPaintEngine@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual int __thiscall QWidget::metric(enum QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric)const " (?metric@QWidget@@MBEHW4PaintDeviceMetric@QPaintDevice@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::initPainter(class QPainter *)const " (?initPainter@QWidget@@MBEXPAVQPainter@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual class QPaintDevice * __thiscall QWidget::redirected(class QPoint *)const " (?redirected@QWidget@@MBEPAVQPaintDevice@@PAVQPoint@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual class QPainter * __thiscall QWidget::sharedPainter(void)const " (?sharedPainter@QWidget@@MBEPAVQPainter@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QMainWindow::setStatusBar(class QStatusBar *)" (__imp_?setStatusBar@QMainWindow@@QAEXPAVQStatusBar@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Ui_GradientSelector::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_GradientSelector@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)setupUi@Ui_GradientSelector@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QWidget::QWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (__imp_??0QWidget@@QAE@PAV0@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Ui_GradientSelector::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_GradientSelector@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QWidget::resize(class QSize const &)" (__imp_?resize@QWidget@@QAEXABVQSize@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Ui_GradientSelector::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_GradientSelector@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QWidget::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QWidget@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void * __thiscall QWidget::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QWidget@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QWidget::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QWidget@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QWidget::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QWidget@@MAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWidget::contextMenuEvent(class QContextMenuEvent *)" (?contextMenuEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQContextMenuEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QPushButton::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QPushButton@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void * __thiscall QPushButton::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QPushButton@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QPushButton::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QPushButton@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QPushButton::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QPushButton@@MAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::timerEvent(class QTimerEvent *)" (?timerEvent@QAbstractButton@@MAEXPAVQTimerEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QPushButton::sizeHint(void)const " (?sizeHint@QPushButton@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QPushButton::minimumSizeHint(void)const " (?minimumSizeHint@QPushButton@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::mousePressEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mousePressEvent@QAbstractButton@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseReleaseEvent@QAbstractButton@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::mouseMoveEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseMoveEvent@QAbstractButton@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QPushButton::keyPressEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyPressEvent@QPushButton@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::keyReleaseEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyReleaseEvent@QAbstractButton@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QPushButton::focusInEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusInEvent@QPushButton@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QPushButton::focusOutEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusOutEvent@QPushButton@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QPushButton::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QPushButton@@MAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::changeEvent(class QEvent *)" (?changeEvent@QAbstractButton@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractButton::hitButton(class QPoint const &)const " (?hitButton@QAbstractButton@@MBE_NABVQPoint@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::checkStateSet(void)" (?checkStateSet@QAbstractButton@@MAEXXZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractButton::nextCheckState(void)" (?nextCheckState@QAbstractButton@@MAEXXZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QLineEdit::metaObject(void)const " metaObject@QMenuBar@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void * __thiscall QMenuBar::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QMenuBar@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QMenuBar::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QMenuBar@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QMenuBar::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QMenuBar@@MAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QMenuBar::eventFilter(class QObject *,class QEvent *)" (?eventFilter@QMenuBar@@MAE_NPAVQObject@@PAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::timerEvent(class QTimerEvent *)" (?timerEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQTimerEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::setVisible(bool)" (?setVisible@QMenuBar@@UAEX_N@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QMenuBar::sizeHint(void)const " (?sizeHint@QMenuBar@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QMenuBar::minimumSizeHint(void)const " (?minimumSizeHint@QMenuBar@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QMenuBar::heightForWidth(int)const " (?heightForWidth@QMenuBar@@UBEHH@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::mousePressEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mousePressEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::mouseReleaseEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseReleaseEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::mouseMoveEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseMoveEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::keyPressEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyPressEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::focusInEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusInEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::focusOutEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusOutEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::leaveEvent(class QEvent *)" (?leaveEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQResizeEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::actionEvent(class QActionEvent *)" (?actionEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQActionEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QMenuBar::changeEvent(class QEvent *)" (?changeEvent@QMenuBar@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QToolBar::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QToolBar@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void * __thiscall QToolBar::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QToolBar@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QToolBar::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QToolBar@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QToolBar::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QToolBar@@MAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QToolBar::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QToolBar@@MAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QToolBar::actionEvent(class QActionEvent *)" (?actionEvent@QToolBar@@MAEXPAVQActionEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QToolBar::changeEvent(class QEvent *)" (?changeEvent@QToolBar@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QStatusBar::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QStatusBar@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual void * __thiscall QStatusBar::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QStatusBar@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual int __thiscall QStatusBar::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QStatusBar@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QStatusBar::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QStatusBar@@MAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QStatusBar::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QStatusBar@@MAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QStatusBar::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QStatusBar@@MAEXPAVQResizeEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "protected: virtual void __thiscall QStatusBar::showEvent(class QShowEvent *)" (?showEvent@QStatusBar@@MAEXPAVQShowEvent@@@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QWidget::~QWidget(void)" (__imp_??1QWidget@@UAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void * __thiscall QWidget::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQWidget@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QPushButton::~QPushButton(void)" (__imp_??1QPushButton@@UAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void * __thiscall QPushButton::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQPushButton@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QLineEdit::~QLineEdit(void)" (__imp_??1QLineEdit@@UAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void * __thiscall QLineEdit::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQLineEdit@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QMenuBar::~QMenuBar(void)" (__imp_??1QMenuBar@@UAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void * __thiscall QMenuBar::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQMenuBar@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QToolBar::~QToolBar(void)" (__imp_??1QToolBar@@UAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void * __thiscall QToolBar::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQToolBar@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QStatusBar::~QStatusBar(void)" (__imp_??1QStatusBar@@UAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void * __thiscall QStatusBar::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQStatusBar@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>GradientSelector.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QMainWindow::QMainWindow(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (__imp_??0QMainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall GradientSelector::GradientSelector(class QWidget *)" (??0GradientSelector@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Photoshop Elements 3.0\Plug-Ins\Filters\tempproj.8bf : fatal error LNK1120: 148 externes non résolus
```

Comment: Are you running moc and including the generated moc sources in your target?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you install MSVC2010. If you did not change the MSVC installation path when you installed it then, your MSVC is on C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0... You should then include your .header files and .lib files on C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include... and C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib.. This is the path where MSVC compiler will look for the header files and .lib files.

Comment: isn't it better to just add the lib and include directories in the option of the VS project ? and btw my installation directory is e:\jeux_install\vs # haha regards (and thanks for help) Jeff

Comment: @IonOne, Yes, It is more better and portable to add a library path in "Library Directory" of "VC++ Directories". (i.e Library Directory = "X:\Directory\Directory\DirectoryThatContainsDotLibFiles;$(LibraryPath) -Don't Forgot semicolon after your path and add $(LibraryPath) always to include default inherited libraries paths value.)